# Casting a video from Django to Angular

Tags: django, angular, video, django-rest-framework

I am building a web application in which I have to upload a video to the server and then, after some analysis, casting it to the frontend which is an Angular application. I can see how to perform the upload, but I cannot find a tutorial or some advice on how to do this. The server is built with Django and django-rest-framework.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload a Video/short clip on the Django Rest API server through angular then follow the steps. I added the backend code here.

**1. Create Class in Django**

```
class VideoClipModel(models.Model):
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='VideoClip', null=True, blank=True)
```

then Do makemigrations and migrate
if want to see the model in the admin panel then add *Model name in the Admin.py file* like

```
admin.site.register(VideoClipModel)
```

and import as well

---

**2. Create Serializer.py file in same app**
add like this

```
class VideoClipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VideoClipModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return VideoClipModel.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

after making serializer file then do 3 step

---

**3. Create View in Django view.py file**

```
class videoClipView(APIView):
      serializer_class = VideoClipSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        queryset = VideoClipModel.objects.all()
        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        jsondata = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=jsondata)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
             serializer.save()
             msg = {'msg':'Add Clip'}
             return Response(msg, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

The last and final steps in django make URLs

---

**4. add URL in urls.py file**

```
path('profile/videoclip/', videoClipView.as_view()),
```

after adding path import path as well

---

> in Angular, you want to make get or post requests to the backend, and
> data passing from angular is in **FormData** format is required. i
> think it will help you